# Find code page by code point and equivalent character

Tags: encoding, cp1252

I have a program, which uses a database to which I have access. This is all on windows and with umlauts and generally horrible.

When I connect to the database with encoding cp1252 I can access the columns with umlauts in the column name.

I now wrote a word with the char `š` (cp1252 code `9A`) and the application displays a `ü`.

**How can I find out which code page the program uses given the code point and the representation?**

I know, the result may be ambiguous, but narrowing the list of possible encodings would also help a lot.

Comment: Important:  `ü` (U+00FC,  *Latin Small Letter U With Diaeresis*)
or `Ü` (U+00DC,  *Latin Capital Letter U With Diaeresis*)?

Comment: The Wikipedia page for `ü` shows that it's represented as 0x9A in code page 437.

Comment: @jasonharper while the hint with cp437 helped a little it still isn't it. `A9` is `©`. This rejects cp437, 850 and 858... I tried clicking through some of the code pages on Wikipedia but to no avail. I'd really like a tool for that. Maybe I need to make it myself...